# Array within an Array (2D Array?)

Tags: ios, arrays, class, swift2

The title probably isn't clear and I'm not sure how to articulate the idea without specifics so here's the rundown:

My code has an array of `Players` (a class I wrote). I want to split the entries in the array evenly (based on their `Players.rating`) between a given number of teams. The problem arises that the number of teams is a var `teamAmount` and can be set between 2 and 8. I'm trying to find a simple way of creating a number of `Player` class arrays equal to the value of `teamAmount` (without having to write 7 switch cases). I was thinking a 2D array, but I can't think of how to initialize it. I feel like it could be simple, but I can't seem to work it out

Comment: I updated my post, it should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted some pseudo-code below. You'll have to modify it to fit the Swift syntax *(I'm away form a Mac at the moment and will edit this when I get home after I throw it in a playground.)*

```
func generate2DArray(players: Array<Player>, numTeams: Int) -> Array<Array<String>>{
  var teams = Array<Array<Player>>()

  for index in 0...numTeams{
      //init the first dimension of empty arrays for each team
      teams.append([Player]())
  }

  for var i = 0; i < players.count; ++i{
    //Place the player in the correct team respectively... (sorry about array syntax, I know its wrong)
      teams[i % numTeams].append(players[i]);
  }
  return teams;
}
```

The basic idea is you know how many teams you want and you can init the first dimension of your 2D array with a simple for loop.

Then to place the players in the respective teams, just use the magical modulus.

*Theory*

- Player 1 % 4 Teams = Belongs on team 1.
- Player 2 % 4 Teams = Belongs on team 2
- Player 3 % 4 Teams = Belongs on team 3.
- Player 4 % 4 Teams = Belongs on team 0.
- Player 5 % 4 Teams = Belongs on team 1.
- Player 6 % 4 Teams = Belongs on team 2.
- Player 7 % 4 Teams = Belongs on team 3.
- Player 8 % 4 Teams = Belongs on team 0.

(Since 4 % 4 is 0, you will have to offset your array, or provide some simple logic to cover that case, the easiest would be to have a team 0 instead of team 4)

**Update**

Just noticed you want them distributed evenly by the players rating. In that case, just make sure you sort the players by their rating before placing them into teams *(I'll omit showing how to do that under the assumption that you know how to sort an array in Swift, comment if help is needed.)*

**Update**

I tested the code I added and made some modifications so that it runs properly in Swift

Here are the results as expected

```
generate2DArray([player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, player6], 2)
//Returns [player1, player3, player5] , [player2, player4, player6]
generate2DArray([player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, player6], 4)
//Returns [player1, player5] , [player2, player6] , [player3] , [player4]
```

Comment: `//init the first dimension of empty arrays for each team` There's my problem. I'm not sure how to initialize that there should be `teamAmount` of teams (the first dimension of the array) I'm probably misunderstanding how it works, I feel like it should be simple

Comment: It should be pretty simple just `teams.append([Player]())` @ImmersionULTD (I'll look at the correct syntax later tonight for initing an array, but its something similar)

Comment: Thanx for the help. I'll accept the answer as soon as I find out the correct syntax

Comment: Just fixed Syntax, I ran the code as is just I replaced the Player for a String object so I wouldn't have to build a Player class, but it should be very easy to swap in.

Comment: Worked on it on my own and fixed the syntax last night. Thanx for the update though

Answer (score 1):

here is an option for you:

```
// e.g. setting up Player(s)
struct Player {
  var rating = 0
}
let players = [Player(rating: 1), Player(rating: 3), Player(rating: 2), Player(rating: 7), Player(rating: 5), Player(rating: 4), Player(rating: 3)]
let sortedPlayers = players.sort { $0.rating > $1.rating }

print(sortedPlayers)
// [Player(rating: 7), Player(rating: 5), Player(rating: 4), Player(rating: 3), Player(rating: 3), Player(rating: 2), Player(rating: 1)]

// e.g. setting up Team(s)
let numberOfTeams = 3
typealias Team = [Player]

// now do the work
let teams = sortedPlayers.enumerate().reduce(
  Array(count: numberOfTeams, repeatedValue: Team()),
  combine: { (var teams, let player) in
    let (playerIndex, player) = player
    teams[playerIndex % numberOfTeams].append(player)
    return teams
  }
)

print(teams)
// [[Player(rating: 7), Player(rating: 3), Player(rating: 1)], [Player(rating: 5), Player(rating: 3)], [Player(rating: 4), Player(rating: 2)]]
```